# Swift 5 timer countdown, while a value is in a range

Tags: swift, timer, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to Countdown from, say, 5 to 0 WHILE the users bearing is between 20 and -20 radian from true north. If bearing remains between 20 and -20 for 5 seconds, segue to new controller. I've tried everything and I have mostly given up.

I've tried a bunch of things, including `scheduleTimer(withInterval 1.0){}`

I am new to Swift. I was unable to invalidate timer.

**Here is the getting user heading**

```
@objc func getUserHeading(_ latitude : Double, _ longitude : Double, _ userLocation : CLLocation){
    let lat1 = (latitude) * .pi / 180
    let long1 = (longitude) * .pi / 180
    
    let lat2 = (yourLocation.coordinate.latitude) * .pi / 180
    let long2 = (yourLocation.coordinate.longitude) * .pi / 180
    print(lat1, long1, lat2, long2)
    
    let dLon = long2 - long1
    
    let y = sin(dLon) * cos(lat2)
    let x = cos(lat1) * sin(lat2) - sin(lat1) * cos(lat2) * cos(dLon)
    
    var radiansBearing = atan2(y, x)
    if radiansBearing < 0 {
        radiansBearing += 2 * Double.pi
    }
    theta = (radiansBearing * 180 / .pi) - (angle)
    print(theta)
    if (theta < 20 && theta > = -20 ){ 
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { timer in 
        print("Timer Fired")
        runCount += 1
        if(theta > 20 && theta < -20)
        {
           self.timer.invalidate()
           self.timerStarted = false
        }
        if (runCount == 5)
        {
           self.timer.invalidate()
           self.segueToNewController()
        }
        
    }
    else{
        timer.invalidate()
        timerStarted = false
    }        
}
```

This is probably a semantics thing, but I swear I have spent DAYS on this and I feel like I am getting no where.

**Issues so far**

1. It does trigger when between 20 and -20 but it triggers immediately and doesn't wait for 5 seconds
2. It triggers MANY times, which means the segue for the next controller is called many times (it caused like 5k writes to my firestore)

If you guys need anything more, please do let me know, will update question with more code.
All help appreciated! End of my wits here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues with your code

- You have 2 contradicting `if` clauses, first you check if `theta` is inside the interval and then inside the `if` clause you check if the same value is outside the interval which will never happen.
- The last `else` looks misplaced
- There are variables you change but never read

I would rewrite it something like this (from the first if)

```
if theta < 20 && theta >= -20 {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { timer in
        print("Timer Fired")
        runCount += 1

        if runCount == 5 {
            timer.invalidate()        
        }
        //theta = ... here you need to somehow update this property to see if it has changed
        if theta > 20 && theta < -20 {
            timer.invalidate()                
        }

    }
} else {
    timer?.invalidate()
}
```

Note that I removed the `timerStarted` variable because I didn't see the point of having it and also not that parentheses are not needed around `if` conditions

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment! So the ```timerStarted``` variable is because the timer is getting triggered more than once, cos the startUpdatingUserHeading() delegate keeps triggering the first if condition. I have the second if condition cos the heading changes are so fast that it (seems) to make it into the first if regardless?

Comment: The else is if the value of theta goes outside the range? No? Christ I feel like the solution is something easy, but I am missing it